# How to find root cause for "too many connections" error in MySQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I'm running a web service which runs algorithms that serve millions of calls daily and run some background processing as well.
Every now and than I see "Too many connections" error in attempts to connect to the MySQL box" for a few seconds. However this is not necessarily attributed to high traffic times or anything I can put my finger on.

I want to find the bottleneck causing it. Other than in the specific times this happens the server isn't too loaded in terms of CPU and Memory, and has 2-3 connections (threads) open and everything works smoothly. (I use Zabbix for monitoring)

Any creative ideas on how to trace it?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on a non-production machine? Have you got a stress testing environment with suitable hardware boxes and a driver system which can simulate production loads? If not, get one as soon as possible. Otherwise you'll have to try to debug it in production, which will involve doing high-risk things like turning on the general query log.

Comment: Update- I have successfully run SHOW PROCESSLIST while the too many connections issue occurred.

What I got is this:
A list of total 151 queries (my num connections is set to 150).
2 of them from my PC (the show processlist)
The rest are all Query commands with time value of 374-395 
Their state is LOCKED besides one who's state is FULLTEXT
3 of the queries are UPDATE all the rest are SELECT.

How can I understand what caused this lockup?

Comment: well it's hard to tell what the cause of the problem is, but I'm pretty sure that it's a query hogging the system. try to see which of them has the longest time of execution and which seems to be repeated a lot. after that, it's just a matter of creating the correct indexes and optimizing your queries, but no one here will be able to tell you exactly what to do without looking at your schema and queries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What MySQL table type are you using? MyISAM or InnoDB (or another one)? MyISAM will use table level locking, so you could run into a scenario where you have a heavy select running, followed by an update on the same table and numerous select queries. The last select queries will then have to wait until the update is finished (which in turn has to wait until the first - heavy - select is finished).

For InnoDB a tool like innotop could be useful to find the cause of the deadlock (see http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/07/31/how-to-analyze-innodb-mysql-locks/).

BTW The query that is causing the lock to occur should be one of those not in locked state.

Comment: My tables at MyISAM, + a few memory tables.

Comment: SHOW PROCESSLIST gave me many queries in lock state and one in FULLTEXT initialization state. The latter has the lowest process id.
Is it certain that the query associated with this process is the locking one?

Comment: It should be, those in LOCKED state are waiting for other queries to finish.

Answer (score 6):

try to have an open mysql console when this happens and issue a

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

to see what queries are being executed. 
Alternatively you could enable logging slow queries (in my.cnf insert this line:

```
log-slow-queries=/var/log/mysql-log-slow-queries.log
```

in the [mysqld] section and use

```
set-variable=long_query_time=1
```

to define what's the minimum time a query should take in order to be considered slow.  (remember to restart mysql in order for changes to take effect)

Answer (score 3):

The [`SHOW OPEN TABLES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-open-tables.html) command will display the lock status of all the tables in MySQL. If one or more of your queries is causing the connection backlock, combining `SHOW PROCESSLIST` and the open tables should narrow it down as to exactly which query is holding up the works.

Comment: I've done SHOW OPEN TABLES while the errors were occuring. I got 

table_name 148 0 

Am I right to assume this table is the locked one? and all connections are blocked in queries to this table?

Comment: '148' means you've got 148 locks active and/or pending on that particular table. Not a big deal if it's InnoDB, since that engine can do row-level locking, but if it's MyISAM it is a big deal, since it can only do table-level locks. If it's InnoDB, you can see what the active queries/locks are via `SHOW INNODB STATUS`. Part of the output of that is a list of queries and errors/locks.

Answer (score 2):

Old topic. However, I just had this issue and it was because I had a mysqldump script scheduled for 3 times per day. At these times, if my web application was also getting a fair amount of usage, all of the web application queries just queued themselves up on top of each other while the mysqldump was locking all of the tables in the database. The best option is to setup a replication slave on a separate machine, and take your backups from the slave rather than from the production server.

Answer (score 1):

May be related to this bug in MySQL for FULLTEXT search:
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=37067

In this case, the FULLTEXT initialization actually hangs MySQL. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing too much of your implementation, and PHP in general, but are you sure that you do not have any problems with lingering DB connections? E.g connections that stay open even after the request has been processed?

In PHP a connection is usually closed automatically when the script ends or when calling `mysql_close($conn);` but if you use any sort of homegrown connection pooling, that could introduce problems.